# Dockerized Node.js server: express route deleted but still available

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, express, docker-compose

So I write a Twitch Chat Bot. Dockerized (docker compose), Node.js v16 with express.

For my authorize-page someone can use to authorize my bot on Twitch API I used the route /auth/request like

```
    this.serverUrl = serverUrl;
    this.port = port;
    this.app = express();
    this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/frontend/'));

    //Landingpage to authorize App for channel
    this.app.get('/auth/request/', (req:any, res:any) => {
        console.log('/');
        var indexhtml = new Replacer().replace(__dirname + '/frontend/auth/request/index.html', '%SERVER_URL%', this.serverUrl);
        res.send(indexhtml);
    });
```

(I am using '%SERVER_URL%' as a placeholer that gets replaced by my localhost or domain-adress.)

First time, there was error, replacing the string and twitch API respondet an error, of course.
But after this, I was not able to change the behavior of the route anymore. Further more, It was still available aber commenting it completely out.

Serveral restarts did not help. Even with

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

I put the route back in, fixed the error an changed the route to "/". I wanted to do that anyway. Here it works fine but at the old route, it is still available with the replace error.
I thougt of some kind of weird deamon services, that are still running, but thats not a thing since it is not available when the container is not running.

I have no further ideas...
How can I get rid of this annoying route? It should not exist anymore.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '0.1'

services: 
    node:
        container_name: sacrificulus
        build: ./app
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - D:\Projects\WebProjects\AlfredServes\app:/app/token_store
        command: ["./node_modules/.bin/ts-node", "./src/bot.ts"]
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ENV TWITCH_CLIENT_ID=12345mytwitchclientid54321

ENV URL_LIVE=https://bot.example.com
ENV PORT_LIVE=80
ENV URL_LOCAL=http://localhost:
ENV PORT_LOCAL=3000

ENV LIVE_OR_LOCAL=local
#ENV LIVE_OR_LOCAL=live

RUN npm install
```

Did anyone had a similar bahavior?

(  Sorry for my code quality :D  )

Comment: But ... did docker-compose rebuild everything after you changed the code??  You should see that in the output of the "docker-compose up".  If it did then you should have been OK.  I like to do an explicit "docker-compose down" before the "up", just to make sure the old one is destroyed.  And I won't disparage your code quality too much, but it would be more efficient in your Dockerfile to COPY just the npm package files, then RUN the npm install, then COPY the rest of the code, so it doesn't have to re-run the npm install after every little code change.

Answer (score 0):

sorry from below's answer. but if you think the code is not changed, try to turn down the container, delete and rebuild. using relative path instead of absolute path for volumes might help.

---

in express code, why dont you use `` res.redirect(`process.env.URL_REDIRECT`) `` ?
with `URL_REDIRECT` pointing either your URL_LIVE or URL_LOCAL.
or even better, make the logic inside your express code,
 `const URL_REDIRECT = (LIVE_OR_LOCAL === 'live')? process.env.URL_LIVE : process.env.URL_LOCAL`

also, why you set env in dockerfile? not in docker-compose? its available (read: https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/ )

also, just noticed, you are using docker-compose version 0.1 instead of recommended of version 3

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question.

Comment: ah, right, my brain focuses on the wrong thing @RitikBanger. going to fix it.